# convert lxml to scrapy xxs selector

Tags: python, xml, screen-scraping, scrapy, lxml

How can I convert this pure python lxml to scrapy built in xxs selectors? This one works but i want to convert this to the scrapy xxs selectors.

```
    def parse_device_list(self, response):
    self.log("\n\n\n List of devices \n\n\n")
    self.log('Hi, this is the parse_device_list page! %s' % response.url)
    root = lxml.etree.fromstring(response.body)
    for row in root.xpath('//row'):
        allcells = row.xpath('./cell')
        # first cell contain the link to follow
        detail_page_link = allcells[0].get("href")
        yield Request(urlparse.urljoin(response.url, detail_page_link ), callback=self.parse_page)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give it a try:

```
def parse_page(self, response):
    xxs = XmlXPathSelector(response)
    for row in xxs.select('//row'):
        detail_page_link = row.select('.//cell[1]/@href')[0].extract()
        yield Request(urlparse.urljoin(response.url, detail_page_link), callback=self.parse_page)
```

Comment: This seems to work but how can I get it to iterate in order for some reason it iterates column A but its out of order. And when the one of the rows in column A is null it grabs column B link. Can I get my method to only get column A and if column A is null to skip it and go to the next row for Column A. Not column B when Column A is empty.